# Using Text Only Once Through Random Method

Tags: android, random, textview

I am new to Android. I am showing Text in the TextView on Button click Randomly. On 1st Textview the Heading and on 2nd the explaination of that heading. I am able to show the Heading and Explaination Randomly and now I want if the Text is shown once should not be shown again means it will be removed. This is the point where I stuck. I am not able to remove the texts. Any help will be appreciated. I am posting my code here.

MainActivity.java

```
TextView text_heading,text_explain;
Button click;
Random random;
Integer [] array_heading ,array_explain ;
Integer int_text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text_heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_heading);
    text_explain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_explain);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            text_heading.setText(array_heading.get(int_text)); //getting error
            text_explain(array_explain.get(int_text)); //getting error
            array_heading.remove(int_text); //getting error
            array_explain.remove(int_text); //getting error
        }
    });

    random = new Random();

    array_heading  = new Integer []{R.string.source_text1, R.string.source_text2, R.string.source_text3,
            R.string.source_text6, R.string.source_text5, R.string.source_text4, R.string.source_text7,
            R.string.source_text8, R.string.source_text9};

    array_explain = new Integer []{R.string.source_text1_explain, R.string.source_text2_explain,
            R.string.source_text3_explain,
            R.string.source_text4_explain, R.string.source_text5_explain, R.string.source_text6_explain,
            R.string.source_text7_explain,
            R.string.source_text8_explain, R.string.source_text9_explain};

    ArrayList<Integer> array_headingList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array_heading));

    ArrayList<Integer>array_explainList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array_explain));


    int_text = random.nextInt(array_headingList.size() - 1);
}
   }
```

Comment: The content of the text isn't relevant, try to keep questions to the bare minimum. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to remove the texts. Any help will be appreciated. I am
>   posting my code here.

To clean the content of the `TextView` you could pass `null` to `setText`. E.g

```
text_heading.setText(null);
```

If you want to change the content every time you click on the button, you have to move

```
int_text = random.nextInt(array_heading.length);
```

your `onClick` callback,

You should be aware of the fact that next int returns an int between `[0, n)`. `array_heading.length -1` is necessary only if you want to exclude `R.string.source_text9_explain` from the possible texts you want to show. Keep also in mind that if `array_heading` contains more items than `array_explain` you could get `ArrayIndexOutBoundException`

Comment: text_heading.setText(null); should be show when all the texts are used once...means i want to use these text once in the textview...

Comment: array_heading & array_explain both are having same number of items....Text showed once will not be repeat....this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

You must use ArrayList for it.

```
ArrayList<Integer> heading = Arrays.asList(array_heading);
ArrayList<Integer> explain = Arrays.asList(array_explain);
```

Now set text from this arraylists. And when its set once remove it from the arraylist so it cannot be shown again.

Use like this

```
random = new Random();

array_heading  = new Integer []{R.string.source_text1, R.string.source_text2, R.string.source_text3,
        R.string.source_text6, R.string.source_text5, R.string.source_text4, R.string.source_text7,
        R.string.source_text8, R.string.source_text9};

array_explain = new Integer []{R.string.source_text1_explain, R.string.source_text2_explain,
        R.string.source_text3_explain,
        R.string.source_text4_explain, R.string.source_text5_explain, R.string.source_text6_explain,
        R.string.source_text7_explain,
        R.string.source_text8_explain, R.string.source_text9_explain};

ArrayList<Integer> array_headingList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array_heading));

ArrayList<Integer> array_explainList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array_explain));

int_text = random.nextInt(array_headingList.size());

click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text_heading.setText(array_headingList.get(int_text)); 
        text_explain.setText(array_explainList.get(int_text)); 
        array_headingList.remove(int_text); 
        array_explainList.remove(int_text);
        if(array_headingList.size() == 0){
          click.setEnabled(false);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"All text finished",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(array_headingList.size() == 1){
        int_text = 0;
        } else {
         int_text = random.nextInt(array_headingList.size());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The text is changing on button click but its get repeated and your if case is not working.....

Comment: edited now check... its repeated because of Random numbers.

Comment: its repeated because of Random numbers..... then "remove" is not doing anything in this

Comment: I am getting text randomly from the starting...my main concern was to remove the text which used or displayed once....and still not solve

Comment: I have tested the code its working.. which errors you getting on your side.?

Comment: I am not getting any error.....just the text are repeating again and again and array_headingList.size() == 0 is not working means the list is not became zero it's showing text on button click every time..

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView text_heading,text_explain;
Button click;
Random random;
Integer [] array_heading ,array_explain ;
Integer int_text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text_heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_heading);
    text_explain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_explain);
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);

    random = new Random();

    array_heading  = new Integer []{R.string.source_text1, R.string.source_text2, R.string.source_text3,
            R.string.source_text6, R.string.source_text5, R.string.source_text4, R.string.source_text7,
            R.string.source_text8, R.string.source_text9};

    array_explain = new Integer []{R.string.source_text1_explain, R.string.source_text2_explain,
            R.string.source_text3_explain,
            R.string.source_text4_explain, R.string.source_text5_explain, R.string.source_text6_explain,
            R.string.source_text7_explain,
            R.string.source_text8_explain, R.string.source_text9_explain};

    ArrayList<Integer> array_headingList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array_heading));

    ArrayList<Integer> array_explainList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array_explain));


    int_text = random.nextInt(array_headingList.size() - 1);

    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            text_heading.setText(array_headingList.get(int_text)); //getting error
            text_explain.setText(array_explainList.get(int_text)); //getting error
            array_headingList.remove(int_text); //getting error
            array_explainList.remove(int_text); //getting error
        }
    });

}
   }
```

Comment: Edited. Should work now. Missed some steps while converting an array to ArrayList

Comment: Confusing--> Use an ArrayList instead of an int array & Note that you will have to change the type of you int arrays to Integer Integer array_heading [], array_explain[]

Comment: An array cannot be changed once it is created, An ArrayList can be. Since you want to delete elements and array will not suit your purpose.

Comment: Also to use Arrays.asList() you will need a wrapper class data type instead of a primitive data type (Integer instead of int in this case). Your Java seems a little rusty. Please refer to java documentations on ArrayList and arrays.

Comment: Edited Again. Also I would suggest you to declare strings needed to be used in java as a Java String directly and only put strings to be used in the xml files in strings.xml

Comment: When I click the button first time it's showing both heading and explain but when i click the button again the text doesn't change it's remain same and I want text to be replace with the next text...

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the strings together in an object:

```
public class Item {
    private final int textId;
    private final int textExplanationId;

    public class Item(int textId, int textExplanationId){
        this.textId = textId;
        this.textExplanationId = textExplanationId;
    }

    public int getTextId(){return textId;}
    public int getTextExplanationId(){return textExplanationId;}
}
```

Then I would store those in an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>(new Item[]{
     new Item(R.string.source_text1, R.string.source_text1_explain),
     new Item(R.string.source_text2, R.string.source_text2_explain),
      //etc
     });
```

Then I would shuffle that array **once**:

```
Collections.shuffle(items);
```

And read from it in order:

```
Item current = items.get(currentIndex++);
text_heading.setText(current.getTextId());
text_explain.setText(current.getTextExplanationId());
```

Comment: By this i will always get the "R.string.source_text1" first but i want the text randomly each time when the user starts the App.

Comment: That's what the shuffle is for